# When redirecting a mobile browser to a m.domain.com subdomain, what status code should I return?

Tags: http, redirect, mobile-devices, apache-2.2

I'm curious what status code I should be using when redirecting a mobile browser that hits domain.com and is redirected to m.domain.com.  I feel like a 301 (Moved Permanently) isn't quite right, but none of the others sound appropriate either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 303 See Other myself, however 300 Multiple Choices (with a properly-formed body describing the various choices) might also be appropriate (although I've never used this myself so have no knowledge of how well-supported it is).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go 302 which is pretty much the default redirect.